# Help studying the derived functor of the limit functor

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, book-recommendation, limits-colimits, derived-functors

I am currently working through the second half of Hatcher's algebraic topology and through Weibel's Homological algbera. In the latter the next chapter I am going to read is the derived functor of the limit functor. And in the former section 3.F discusses this as well.

I was wondering if any of you had any suggestion to best read these two different sources to get the most out of each. To be clear, I will be anyway reading both, but want to make this as efficient and fruitful as possible.

Any tips or even opinions are accepted.